# StyleCop Rule for Multiline Curly Brackets

Tags: c#, coding-style, stylecop

SA1503 in StyleCop is an all or nothing deal when it comes to curly brackets. I want to be able to allow the following code:

```
if (x == 3) return true;
```

But disallow the following:

```
if (x == 3)
    return true;

if (x == 3)
    foreach (var w in widgets)
        x++;
```

So basically, same line without curly brackets good, multi-line without curly brackets bad.

I'm new to writing custom StyleCop rules and I'm struggling with where to begin. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've wanted the same styles, and had to turn off the rules `StatementMustNotBeOnSingleLine` and `CurlyBracketsMustNotBeOmitted` to support it. This now supports the single line scenario, but unfortunately doesn't check the multi line scenario.

However I don't think this should be a new rule, but rather a change to the current rules (maybe configurably controlled). I suggest raising an issue on the [StyleCop site](http://stylecop.codeplex.com/workitem/list/basic), and if you're game get the [source](http://stylecop.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/8b3831e38d66) and make the change. There is a [developer guide](http://stylecop.codeplex.com/documentation) in the documentation which will help get you started.

Comment: Do they implement their rules as we would implement a custom rule? If I could locate the source of a rule it would be a big help in beginning to write a custom rule.

Comment: Could *could* possibly look at [StyleCop+](http://stylecopplus.codeplex.com/) which has support for [custom rules](http://stylecopplus.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=How%20to%20Create%20StyleCop%20Custom%20Rule&referringTitle=Documentation). I've never used it so I have no idea how good it is.

Comment: If you play with StyleCop directly, there is a `StyleCopSDK` doc in the `Project/Docs` folder which may help.

Comment: Finally - if you want to tweak the existing rules, then take a look at [LayoutRules.cs](http://stylecop.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/8b3831e38d66#Project%2fSrc%2fAddIns%2fCSharp%2fAnalyzers%2fLayoutRules.cs)